How many four-digit numbers abcd are there such that a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d?
I understand how to get a<b<c<d, however, I don't know how to approach this problem when ≤ is used instead of <.

Welcome to MSE. So how did you do the problem with "$<$". Please edit your question to provide details.

By the way the answer is not the same as the linked question if you don't allow leading zeros. However there is an easy fix.
